# How to add Segmented controll on UIToolBar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to add segmented control on toolbar, I'm adding but not shows.
  my code is: these code is on viewDidload

```
    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 325.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
     NSArray *segmentItem = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Day",@"List",@"Month", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControll = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segmentItem];
    segmentControll.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 325.0, 200.0, 30.0);   

    //[self.toolBar addSubview:segmentControll];

    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentControll];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can add only the *UIBarButtonItem's* to *UIToolbar*.**

First, add the segmentControll to a bar button item,

```
UIBarButtonItem *segBarBtn;
segBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentControl];
```

Add the bar button to the tool bar,

```
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:segBarBtn];
[toolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

Comment: This is correct but the user should not be trying to add items to the UINavigationControllers toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `self.navigationController.toolbar` is not the same as `toolBar`.

**2.** You're doing it wrong. You should add `segmentControl` as `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControll];
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:btnItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regular UIToolbar you do so by making the segmented control a part of a custom `UIBarButtonItem` like this.

```
UIBarButtonItem * segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: segmentControll];
NSMutableArray *itemCopy = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
[itemCopy addObject:segmentBarItem];
self.toolbar.items = itemCopy;

[itemCopy release];
[segmentBarItem release];
```

But in your case you are trying to modify the toolbar of a navigation controller which is discouraged.

> This property contains a reference to the built-in toolbar managed by
>   the navigation controller. Access to this toolbar is provided solely
>   for clients that want to present an action sheet from the toolbar. You
>   should not modify the UIToolbar object directly.

You will still want to create a custom UIBarButtonItem but you will want to set it as the [`rightBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItem)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 325.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
 NSArray *segmentItem = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Day",@"List",@"Month", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentControll = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segmentItem];
segmentControll.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 325.0, 200.0, 30.0);   

//[self.toolBar addSubview:segmentControll];

UIBarButtonItem *toolbarItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl] autorelease];
[toolBar addSubview:toolbarItem];

[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```